# What domain should I use in production for Circuit SDK bot's client?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I created a bot in my own sandbox using Circuit JS SDK.

```
self.client = new Circuit.Client({
                client_id: config.client_id,
                client_secret: config.client_secret,
                domain: config.domain,
                autoRenewToken: true
            });
```

Here domain value was **"circuitsandbox.net"**

Now I want to connect it with bot's account in real Circuit Enterprise domain. What value should I use for domain now? How can I find this if I'm not an administrator of domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain will be the system your tenant is located at. You can see this in the URL you use for your circuit client. Unless its a special onprem deployment, the production domain will be either eu.yourcircuit.com or na.yourcircuit.com.

If you don't have a production tenant yet, you can request a free tenant. See step 3 at https://circuit.github.io/